# Chaquopy not initializing class

Tags: android, chaquopy

When using chaquopy for android, calling a module from java does not run the `__init__` method.

```
PyObject utilModule = py.getModule("utils.Utils").get("Utils");
```

Creates an object reference to python without the constructor. Is there any way to do this without an additional "init" function and calling that after creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `utils.Utils` is a module, and `Utils` is a class within that module, your code is just getting a reference to that class. If you want to actually instantiate the class, you can either do this:

```
PyObject utilObj = py.getModule("utils.Utils").callAttr("Utils");
```

or this:

```
PyObject utilClass = py.getModule("utils.Utils").get("Utils");
PyObject utilObj = utilClass.call();
```

If you want to pass constructor parameters, just add them at the end of the parameter list of `callAttr` or `call`.

See the `ZipFile` example in [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/java.html).